# When Tooltip.Content gets populated?

Tags: wpf, tooltip, contentcontrol

I need to use the Tooltip.Content information of any given control.

Lets say there is a a control `TextBlock` and it is bound to a `Tooltip`. I access the Tooltip of the TextBlock by `var toolTip=(ToolTip)TextBlock.ToolTip`.  The value of `toolTip.Content` remains null, but if I do a mouse hover over the control it is populated with the desired value.

How do I get the tooltip to populate its content before triggering a mouse over the control? Does the Tooltip loads its content lazily or is there something I am missing?

**Edit:**

To clarify the question above:

I was trying to show tooltip but its content was not populated with the binding value although its bound to a valid property.

Comment: Did you try just string from TextBlock.ToolTip?

Comment: @Blam TextBlock.ToolTip as a string worked fine for me if it was a hardcoded string. Problem is when it was a binding. The binding value was not picked. Setting the PlacementTarget solved the binding Issue for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found answer to my own question, Tooltip control doesn't get created until it is necessary. And when it gets created it sets is `PlacementTarget` to the parent control and sets its `IsOpen` property to true. When 'PlacementTarget`is set it populates the`ToolTip.Content` property.

In my case I was just trying to set `IsOpen` property without setting the `PlacementTarget`. Now after setting it the content is bound and the tooltip is shown as expected.